# Visual Studio - how to fix paths in binary project files?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2003

In MS Visual Studio 2003, I have several related projects and solutions inherited from other developers.

Some binary files (with extensions including ncb, opt, idb, pdb, and pch) reference absolute file-system paths that don't exist on my PC but did on the previous developers' PCs.

One or more of the projects seem to depend on these paths, because the paths appear in the "Resolve Ambiguity" dialog-box when I try "Go To Definition" in source files in some projects.

I have checked the properties of all the solutions and projects in Visual Studio and can't find any reference to these paths. How can I change or remove them without directly editing the binary files?

**Edit:**
I've used a third-party text-editor to search all file types in the whole directory tree for these solutions and projects.
I've searched for the bad paths containing both single and double-backslashes.
Also, one of the paths contains a username, so I've searched for just the username without the rest of the path.
*All* of the bad paths are referenced only in binary files. They don't appear in any source-code, solution (.sln) or project (.vcproj) files.

Comment: did you try searching for the filename instead of the path? Also paths in strings have escaped backslashes \\, but in the binary its \ so your search might miss that

Comment: @thumbmunkeys - see the edit to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved...
According to other resources, the binary files can be deleted.
I deleted those files and rebuilt the solution, which caused Visual Studio to recreate the binary files, and now there's no reference to the nonexistent paths.

I had thought the path references might be the cause of a problem I had running a test application for the solution, but that turned out to be unrelated - the test app was loading an old DLL from C:\Windows\SysWOW64 when I expected it to be using my latest built version.